# Как сделать импорт из каталога уровнем выше?

Tags: python, python-import

У меня есть файлы

```
abc/bot.py
payment.py
bot.py
```

Я запускаю `abc/bot.py` и мне нужно импортировать `payments.py`, то есть каким-то образом перейдите в каталог выше. Я пытался

```
от.. импорт платежа
из ..импорт платежа отправить
```

Я получил сообщение об ошибке ImportError: предпринята попытка относительного импорта без известного родителя, и все. Что делать?

Comment: Замените `от.. импорт платежа`
`из ..импорт платежа отправить` на то что вы действительно пытались прописать, а то не понятно что там во втором случае, `from .. import payment send`, так что ли?

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать `os.chdir(path)` чтобы указать точный путь/каталог который вам нужен

Comment: а как импортировать файл? у меня пишет No module named 'payments'

Comment: Тогда можно попробовать использовать модуль shutil. Почитать можно [тут](https://pythonworld.ru/moduli/modul-shutil.html)

Answer (score 0):

Костыльный способ: добавить внешнюю папку в переменную окружения PYTHONPATH, тогда можно будет из нее импортировать просто по имени:

`abc/bot.py:`

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path
# __file__ - путь текущего файла, из него получаем путь к директории выше
sys.path.append(str(Path(__file__).parent.parent))  
import payment
```

---

Другой вариант: считать, что вся папка, где лежит код - это пакет, и запускать код в ней как модуль.

Структура каталогов:

```
.
└── some_bot
    ├── abc
    │   └── bot.py
    ├── bot.py
    └── payment.py
```

Файл `some_bot/abc/bot.py`:

```
from ..payment import send
# Или from some_bot.payment import send

send()
```

Файл `some_bot/payment.py`:

```
def send():
    print("send something")
```

Из командной строки, находясь в директории снаружи `some_bot`, запускаем:

```
> python3 -m some_bot.abc.bot
send something
```

Ключевое тут: чтобы работал абсолютный (`from some_bot.payment import send`) или относительный (`from ..payment import send`) импорт, код должен запускаться как пакет, снаружи пакета. Не двойным кликом по файлу `abc/bot.py` или командой `python abc/bot.py`, а через `python` с ключом `-m`, иначе будет ошибка `ImportError` (при относительном импорте - что не известен родительский пакет, при абсолютном - что пакет с таким именем не найден).

В целом, если положить снаружи пакета `some_bot` модуль python, и в нем прописать `import some_bot.abc.bot`, то это будет аналогично запуску `python -m some_bot.abc.bot` из командной строки.

---

Вообще, для простого проекта я бы не заморачивался с пакетами, а просто все запускаемые файлы перенес на внешний уровень (логично же, чтобы "пульт управления" был на виду, а не был спрятан где-то глубоко в папках), а вспомогательные разложил по папкам при необходимости, тогда из запускаемых файлов будет работать "простой" импорт.

Про пакеты можно почитать, например, тут: [Пакеты Python — создание и доступ](https://pythononline.ru/osnovy/pakety-python)

Только я не добавлял файл `__init__.py`, есть отличия в пакетах с таким файлом и без него, но в данном случае это не критично.
Детально про `__init__.py` можно почитать тут: [Is `__init__.py` not required for packages in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48804718/4752653).